# How can low-rep users edit my posts?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

How is possible that somebody with little reputation (as little as 20) can edit my posts? I got a notification about a suggested edit, but I couldn't find how to reject it, and when I opened the post, the changes were there and I had to undo them manually.

Comment: A person with little reputation cannot edit your post unanimously. They suggest an edit. This is then sent to be approved/rejected. This can be done by either 2 members with 2k+ reputation (3 on some sites) or by the owner of the post.

In this case the suggested edit had already been approved by other 2k+ community members. If the changes make the post worse rolling back the edit is the right thing to do but try to keep any good changes that were made.
 This is it.

Comment: @stackoverloop I'm fairly sure I just said that

Comment: @RichardTingle sorry didn't see that ;)

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4001251) the suggested edit in question? If so I see your point. The edit was ultimately approved but 1 user did vote to reject

Comment: @RichardTingle right, that one.

Comment: @NullOfZes that was a fair edit, you're just ranting. Maybe he wanted to gain some rep and you wouldn't let him (and the edit was fair anyway)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A person with little reputation cannot edit your post unilaterally. They **suggest** an edit. This is then sent to be approved/rejected. This can be done by either 2 members with 2k+ reputation (3 on some sites) or by the owner of the post.

In this case the suggested edit had already been approved by other 2k+ community members. If the changes make the post worse rolling back the edit is the right thing to do but try to keep any good changes that were made.

Comment: Correct. See [Help Center > Privileges > edit questions and answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). Users with < 2k rep can suggest edits; users with > 2k rep can edit immediately (and approve suggested edits made by members with < 2k rep).

Comment: @Richard Tingle +1 that was the same I thought.

Comment: @Cerran me too +1

Comment: can someone transform my "+1" comment in a upvote to this kind sir who took the time to write this insightful answer? :)

Comment: @stackoverloop I'm afraid upvoting is a 15 rep privilege

Comment: @RichardTingle that's why I asked someone else to transform it in a upvote :)